# Is there a setting in Visual Studio that affects the location a custom DLL function creates a file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I have written custom DLL with a function for a scripting language that works with pdf's. When i call my create function it works but it creates the pdf in my C++ Project debug directory. I am not specifying a fully qualified path as im testing. Is there a setting that could control that in visual studio and somehow be in the dll? If i specify a full path it returns an error, assuming because it is starting in my project folder... Anyone know of this?

```
MV_EL_FunctionParameter pdfApCreate_parameters[] = {
    { "filename", 8, EPF_NORMAL },
    { "location", 8, EPF_NORMAL }
};
__declspec(dllexport) void bi_pdfApCreate(mvProgram prog, mvVariableHash parameters, mvVariable returnvalue, void **)
{
    int ret = LoadApWDll();
    if (!ret)
    {
        mvVariable_SetValue_Integer(returnvalue, 33333);
        return;
    }


    // INPUTS
    int filename_len;
    const char* filename;
    int location;

    // OUTPUT
    long id;

    // Not needed anymore, for a depricated Miva API function.
    //char* resolved_filename = NULL;
    //int resolved_filename_len;

    filename = mvVariable_Value(mvVariableHash_Index(parameters, 0), &filename_len);
    location = file_location(mvVariableHash_Index(parameters, 1));
    //mvFile_Resolve(prog, location, filename, filename_len, &resolved_filename, &resolved_filename_len);
    
    id = pApCreate((char*)filename);
    if (id) { mvProgram_Free(prog, const_cast<char*>(filename)); }
    mvVariable_SetValue_Integer(returnvalue, id);

}
```

This is where people leave. This is creating the function for Miva script language. It is their custom API im using to build it.
Here is an image of Miva Mia.[image: Miva Mia Web Server]

Comment: "*it creates the pdf in my C++ Project debug directory. I am not specifying a fully qualified path*" - that is your mistake. ALWAYS use absolute paths, NEVER use relative paths. You don't know where the calling process's "Current Working Directory" is pointing at any given moment. Even if you called `SetCurrentDirectory() in your code, it is a race condition. "*Is there a setting that could control that in visual studio*" - this is not something you should be controlling in project settings. "*If i specify a full path it returns an error*" - then you are doing something wrong with it...

Comment: ... If needed, you can build up an absolute path at runtime from pieces of paths.  For instance, if you need an absolute file path that is relative to your DLL, you can retrieve the path of your DLL at runtime, truncate off its filename, and append the new folder/filename as needed.  But, since you are trying to create new files, you should be using folders that Windows has set aside for that purpose, such as creating your own subfolder under system folders like `%APPDATA%` or `MyDocuments`, which you can get the paths to by asking Windows using `SHGetFolderPath()` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath()`.

Comment: OK... In my script code i do not need to specify a fully qualified path because my webserver application specifies that all ready. I am not using any path information in the C++ code i posted above. There is no path information in that code. That code creates a Function i call in another language where i send it the path to create the pdf.

Comment: "*where i send it the path to create the pdf*" - and what kind of path are you sending it exactly?  A relative path, or an absolute path? If relative, is the function in question smart enough to convert that path into an absolute path defined by the webserver, before the path is handled to Windows to actually create the file? If the path is relative, and is just given to Windows as-is, then you are subject to the webserver's "Current Working Directory", which could be pointing *anywhere* at any time.  You are really not providing useful details to help you with.

Comment: When it is called the function takes a location parameter which is specifically script,or data. Depending on which it is Miva creates the full path designated by whatever path i have set in the webserver.

Comment: Well, then either the webserver is configured to point that full path to your project's debug folder where you said you don't want it, or else Miva/webserver is not actually behaving the way you have described and the full path does not get set to any specific folder at all, so Windows has to pick a folder for you. Again, there is really no way to answer this given the limited details you have provided.

Comment: Sorry for the limited details. The code above is compiled in VS and using Miva API header file creates a function called pdfApCreate that can be called by miva. That function is passed a literal filename (file to create) and location which is 'script' or 'data'. The compiled dll is placed into Miva webserver application (called Mia) folder. In Mia settings i register/add the dll. In Mia settings "script" location is set and 'data' folder is set. (these paths work for everything else i do) I create a simple script in Miva that calls this function. Mia finds it in the dll and calls the function.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're writing to Win32 (vs. .Net, or .Net Core).

I would *NOT* recommend a "hard coded path" - that's too brittle.

Rather, I would suggest one of:

- Read the path from an environment variable
- Use a path relative to the .exe

To get the path in Win32:

```
TCHAR szFileName[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, szFileName, MAX_PATH)
```

To get the path in .Net:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)
```

If you choose to use environment variables:

- You *CAN* set the variable in Visual Studio
- For "production", you'd probably call your .exe from a .bat file, and set the environment variable in the .bat file

Yet another option is to have the *.exe* determine the path, and pass the path string to the .dll as a function argument :)

Comment: I do not use a hard coded path. The path is sent to this function as a parameter. Yes it is Win32.

Comment: There is no guarantee the user has write access to the folder with that .dll file; there are folders in Windows that would most likely have such access, for example LOCALAPPDATA

Comment: "Yet another option is to have the .exe determine the path, and pass the path string to the .dll as a function argument :)" This is exactly what im doing. It is not called from an .exe though. It is being called from a Miva script which is a compiled .mvc

Comment: OK, so your .dll is invoked by the script.  The .dll is reading parameters `filename` and `location`, passed to it from the script.  Q: Please give examples of these two values, when you running in "test mode" in MSVS?  One example with "full path" (gives an error), the other that "works" (writes to your MSVS project directory)?

Comment: Exactly Paul. Vlad pointed me in a direction to be able to debug this attaching it to my web server executable. I have found the problem. Function MvFile_Resolve is a deprecated function in the API and its job was to get the data or script location from the web server, concatenate that with the filename/path sent in the function to create the full path. That was not happening. Now i need to find a way to grab that info and this should be fixed. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't realize you didn't know about how to set a bkpt in your .dll, then "MSVS > Debug > Attach to process".  Glad you know now :)  Per my last comment: 1) I'd still like to see examples of `filename` and `location`.  2) I suspect all you have to do is modify the "location" string ... and everything will work as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has a setting that specifies `Working Directory`, but that is only used while running from the Visual Studio.

However, you should NEVER rely on the current working directory. Specify the full path.

Please show the code that "returns an error" - it might be your fault.

Comment: Im sure its my fault! I do not understand where it would get that directory information. I run a Miva mia web server and the locations for data,and scripts are set in that application. The DLL is located in C:\Mivamia\Builtins\mrdll.dll...

Comment: @SquishyBrain I see you added the code. I am not familiar with Miva. Regardless, what is the value of `filename` when you call `pApCreate`?

Comment: Im sorry that was wrong. That is simply the filename. Location is the path.

Comment: @SquishyBrain Vlad asked you for the *actual value* of `filename`.  What does it actuallylook like at runtime? Please give an example.

Comment: I dont know this is not an exe its a dll build how can i get that information?

Comment: @SquishyBrain you place a breakpoint on that line, run the Debugger, and when it stops there - look at the value in the `Autos` or `Watch` window.

Comment: It is a dll build. I cant place a breakpoint on this or run it debugging. It is not an exe.

Comment: @SquishyBrain you most certainly can debug the dll code.

Comment: Sweet. Well i cant do it like any exe it gives me an error if i try to run debugging.

Comment: Is there a tutorial or something you could link ?

Comment: @SquishyBrain https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/?view=vs-2019

Comment: @SquishyBrain in Studio, go to Project's Property, Configuration Properties -> Debugging. In the `Command` field type the name of your executable, then `F5`

Comment: I do not have an executable.

Comment: @SquishyBrain you DO have an executable (those are the only things you can run). It may be that `Miva` itself. If it is running all the time, select `Attach` on that Property Page.

Comment: Ahh yes Mia.exe... I added it into the debugging command line and chose Attach = yes.

Comment: Wow. Thank you Vlad! I knew you could attach to a running process for debugging i had no idea you could do that. The filename is not the full path. MvFile_resolve function that has been deprecated was grabbing the location from Miva mia or Empressa and building the fully qualified path. Without that my script was just sending a filename. Thank you very much for sticking around. Now i have to find another way to get that information. Thanks man!

Comment: @Vlad Feinstein: I strongly disagree with your premise.  I believe callers should ALWAYS prefer a relative path whenever practical.  Relative to "something" (not necessarily the .exe install directory).  I definitely appreciate your telling the OP about "MSVS > Attach" - I didn't realize he didn't know that.require a full path.  It sounds like the entire problem might have been "mvFile_Resolve()" ... and that the OP has a viable workaround.

Comment: @paulsm4 OK, thank you very much for this explanation. I guess we disagree. So you are saying that `Current Working Directory` is something the developer should rely on?

Comment: For many applications, yes.  A subdirectory relative to CWD might be ideal.  Since Windows Vista (ancient history), that won't work for Windows apps installed in (user-read-only) "Program files\".  So a subdirectory relative to %LOCALAPPDATA% is often a better choice.  Or relative to some custom variable (set by a .bat file), like %MYAPPROOT%.  *ANYTHING* but a hard-coded, full path.  Ideally, the "full" path should be appended from some configurable "root" directory, instead of being dictated by the top-level caller.  IMHO...